# Shapeless could not find implicits

Tags: scala, implicit, shapeless, hlist

I'm trying to generate objects via `shapeless`
With this code snippet:

```
import shapeless._
case class T1(i: Int, v: String)

class WorkbenchSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
  "Gen tests" should "do smth interesting" in {
    println(ObjectGenerators.gen(classOf[T1]))
  }
}

object FieldGen extends Poly0 {
  implicit val genInt = at[Int](0)
  implicit val genString = at[String]("")
}

object ObjectGenerators {

  def gen[T, TRepr <: HList](c: Class[T])
                            (implicit
                             gen: Generic.Aux[T, TRepr],
                             fill: ops.hlist.FillWith[FieldGen.type, TRepr]
                            ): T = {

    gen.from(HList.fillWith[TRepr](FieldGen))
  }

  def fillList[T <: HList](implicit fill: ops.hlist.FillWith[FieldGen.type, T]) =
    fill()
}
```

I get an error:

> could not find implicit value for parameter fillWith:
>   shapeless.ops.hlist.FillWith[com.media.gr.core.ObjectGenerators.FieldGen.type,gen.Repr]
>       gen.from(HList.fillWithgen.Repr)

But in `sbt` console if I do:

```
case class T1(i: Int, v: String)
object FieldGen extends Poly0 {
  implicit val genInt = at[Int](0)
  implicit val genString = at[String]("")
}
def gen[T, TRepr <: HList](c: Class[T])
                            (implicit
                             gen: Generic.Aux[T, TRepr],
                             fill: ops.hlist.FillWith[FieldGen.type, TRepr]
                            ): T = {

    gen.from(HList.fillWith[TRepr](FieldGen))
  }
```

I get generated result. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Put `WorkbenchSpec` definition after `FieldGen` and `ObjectGenerators`, or into another file. It's an old problem where Scala sometimes can't find implicit vals, if they are defined later in the same file.

Comment: ah! thx! you made my day